Turn off beep when doing a Save As for an existing file
How can I turn off the beep that occurs when I do a Save As for a file that already exists?
It only occurs with Geany and Pluma.
I looked all through /usr/share/sounds and then the entire hard disk. None of the sound files matches. If I found the sound, I would rename it.
Maybe the sound is embedded the the Operating System ? :-)
I am using Ubuntu Mate 24.04.
Thanks.

The answer is to check the mute box for the alert volume.

